# Find particular elements in a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $T: V\rightarrow V$ be the linear transformation described below, where $V$ is the linear space of all real function on $[-\pi,\pi]$.
$$
g(x) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1+\cos(x-t))f(t) dt $$
Find all real $c\neq 0$ and $f$ in $V$ such that $T(f) = cf$

Comment: How far did you get? where did you get stuck? where did you come upon this problem, and why is solving it important?

Comment: I don't really have any idea where to start on it, so I didn't really get far at all. I do know a basis of T is ${1, \cos x, \sin x}$ but I can't really figure out a way to make it workable. The problem's from one of apostol's textbooks

Comment: $T$ is a linear transformation, not a vector space. What do you mean by "a basis of $T$"? Is anything like this problem done elsewhere in the book?

Comment: By basis of T I meant the basis of T(V); should've been more clear on that. I'm pretty early into the book, but so far I don't think I've seen anything similar.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469424/show-that-tv-is-finite-dimensional by the way, you should accept that answer if it helped you (the check mark under the voting arrows).

Comment: You forgot to say anything about $T$. I suppose the formula you gave defines $g=T(f)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You know from the other question that $T(V)$ is spanned by the (linearly independent) set $S=\{1,\cos x,\sin x\}$. If $T(f)=cf$, $c\neq0$, then
$$
f=\frac1c T(f)\in T(V),
$$
so you know that $f\in L(S)$. (I denote by $L(S)$ the 3-dimensional space spanned by $S$.)

So we have reduced the question to an eigenvector problem involving a 3-dimensional space $L(S)$, and a linear transformation $T:L(S)\to L(S)$. Next you might calculate the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $S$.

Comment: BTW: If you haven't proved that $S$ is linearly independent in $V$, then for full credit you should do that step here as well.

Comment: Peripherally relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace.